# List of IE9 Standards Mode changes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, xhtml-1.0-strict, quirks-mode

I would like a (extensive) list of changes that have been made to the behavior of IE9 in standards mode.

As an example, I recently debugged an issue in SWFObject and found that IE9 now returns `typeof stylesheet.addRule == "function"` instead of "object".

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 Guide for Developers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705

Comment: [IE 10 preview is available](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE9 guide for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705) is a complete overview of new features and improvements.

Comment: Was hoping for a better list as that list doesn't actually cover things like the example I gave in the OP.  It'd be nice if they had an issue tracker or changelog.  But I guess that's asking a bit much.

Comment: You could look through the fixed bugs for IE9 in the feedback program, but I wouldn't recommend it. http://connect.microsoft.com/ie/